# Guardar y recuperar un ultimo valor en memoria flash

Tags: c++, esp32

intento hacer un generador de turnos guardando valores numéricos en la memoria flash con el fin de que si se desconecta el microcontrolador, dichos valores generados no se borren.
Los valores se generan después de presionar un botón, y comienza en 1 hasta el numero 10. si se presiona nuevamente lo que ocurre es que ahora se generaran valores del 1 al 20, y si presiono nuevamente se generan valores del 1 al 30 y así sucesivamente. Este comportamiento se debe a que como mencione anteriormente, trabajo un generador de turnos, por lo que cada vez que presiono el botón genero 10 turnos adicionales.

La cuestión es que no puedo imprimir los valores guardados que se guardan con anterioridad en la memoria flash.
Me explico, si por ejemplo, genero 30 turnos(presione 3 veces el botón) estos valores son impresos conforme presiono el botón, lo cual esta bien, pero si desconecto el dispositivo los valores se reinician y vuelven a contar desde el 1 nuevamente.

Lo que he intentando es guardar el ultimo valor limite del contador y guardar aquel valor en la memoria flash para así poder recuperar el ultimo valor guardado al que el contador llego para poder recuperarlo aun después  de desconectar el microcontrolador, aunque sin éxito.
Me explico, si los turnos llegaron por ejemplo a 40(pulsador pulsado 4 veces) dicho valor 40, debería guardarse en la memoria flash y cuando se desconecte y vuelva a conectar el dispositivo debería recuperar dicho valor e de imprimir valores del 1 al 40(ya que uso un ciclo for para ello), pero simplemente se reinicia y empieza a contar desde 1 de 10 en 10.

aquí esta el código:

```
#include <Preferences.h>

Preferences preferences;

const int buttonPin = D0; // Pin del botón
int buttonState = 0;      // Estado actual del botón
int lastButtonState = 0;  // Estado anterior del botón
bool buttonPressed = false;
int i=0;
int li=10;
int count=1;
int tope=0;
int aux=0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial); // espera a que la conexión serial esté lista

  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP); // Configura el pin del botón como entrada con resistencia de pull-up

  // Inicia las preferencias
  preferences.begin("storage", false);
}

void loop() {
  // Lee el estado del botón
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // Comprueba si el botón ha sido presionado
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    if (buttonState == LOW) {
      // Botón presionado
      buttonPressed = true;
    }
  }

  lastButtonState = buttonState;

  // Si el botón ha sido presionado
  if (buttonPressed) {
    // Guarda los números del 1 al 10 en la memoria flash
    for (i = count; i <= li; i++) {
      String key = "number" + String(i);
      preferences.putUInt(key.c_str(), i); // Guarda el número en la memoria flash
      if(i==10)
      {
        li=li+10;
      }
    }

    if(li>tope)
    {
      tope=li;
     preferences.putUInt("tope", li);
     tope = preferences.getUInt("tope");
    }

    for(int j= 1; j<=tope; j++)
    {
      String ca = "number" + String(j);
      Serial.println(preferences.getUInt(ca.c_str()));
    }


    buttonPressed = false; // Reinicia el indicador de botón presionado
  }



  delay(100); // Pequeña pausa para estabilidad
  preferences.end();
}
```

Comment: Creo que la información modificable por el programa se guarda en la EEPROM

Comment: El microcontrolador que utilizo no tiene EEPROM, pero tiene flash el cual cumple la misma funcionalidad

Answer (score 1):

Con [`begin`](https://espressif-docs.readthedocs-hosted.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/api/preferences.html#begin) abres un namespace y con [`end`](https://espressif-docs.readthedocs-hosted.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/api/preferences.html#end) lo cierras.

Es necesario que haya un namespace abierto para leer y escribir en la memoria. Sin embargo en el código lo abres una única vez y lo cierras siempre, aún si ya estuviera cerrado.

Con quitar `preferences.end()` debería funcionar correctamente. Creo que no necesitas llamar esa función a menos que quieras abrir otro namespace.